# Debugging Visual-studio

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a problem with debugging. It just stops when I have a query to my database.

```
Try
        Dim sqlCommand As String = "SELECT AdmBemanning FROM SystemBrukere"
        Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, SQLConnection)


        Dim resultTable As New DataTable
        sqlAdapter.Fill(resultTable) ------- the debugger stops here.

        Return resultTable(0)(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
```

System:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5

Microsoft.Net Framework
Version 4.5.51209

Window 7 Professional
Service Pack 1

Comment: What happens if you run SQL profiler while the query is running?

Comment: reason might be your fill is running for long time or returning huge data

Comment: Would you suggest to try a query like: `SELECT TOP 10 AdmBemanning FROM SystemBrukere`?

Comment: Slight detour...you really need to do something in your catch. Returning an empty string is an anti-pattern I call try-squelch. If there is an error you need to know about it so you can fix it.

Comment: Probably just a long-running query - you are fetching the whole table just to get (0)(0)! Not good. Change your SQL instead.

Comment: `Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, SQLConnection)` I believe that is your problem. You are **not** using an instance of `SQLConnection`... Instead you are just using the class... Create a new variable to instantiate the `SQLConnection` class and then pass that to your adapter. If I am wrong then ***show us where you instantiate*** `SQLConnection`...

Comment: Thank for all your answers. I will comment back on them soon.

Comment: The program itself runs just fine. It is the debugging part which is my problem.

Comment: The result from the query is only one row.

Comment: Just to complete some suggestions above: Why not to SELECT TOP 1 if you only use 1 row from the query?? Apart from the fact, that you can use a different sqlclient method of getting 1 value.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions about the code. The problem is not the code. The program is running - the debugger is not. Today the debugger is working again...

Comment: And then it stopped again.. What is wrong? It just worked and now it stops?

Comment: I have no found the problem. It was the firewall. We are using Symantec.cloud - Endpoint Protection NIS-22.5.4.24. Does anybody know which port to open?

Comment: Please share a simple sample about the detailed code, for the firewall or other tools, can you disable/close them? Do you get any debugging exception messages?

Comment: I can just disable the firweall and then I have no problems with debugging. I do not get any exception messages.

Comment: How long do you leave it when it 'just stops'? iirc the default timeout is 30 sec which can feel like a long time when you're used to each line of code executing instantaneously. Maybe you would get an error message if you left it a bit longer.

Comment: I have tried for over 10 minutes... It just stops. Before the last update of Symantec, it was idling for about 1-2 minutes, but after the last update it just stops.

Comment: @Kim, please allow some apps to communicate through firewall under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\Allowed apps, if you debug your app as the admin, or debug your app in release mode, how about the result?

Answer (score 0):

Since it works well after you disable the firewall, so the possible reason is related to the port.

Like the document here:

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO81103.html

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH163787.html

Communication between a SEPM and a Microsoft SQL Database Server if they reside on separate computers uses the default port 1433.